# resource ids on test database does not match on rspec run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When I run rspec I find following errors

```
Module #4: Navigation Tests rq05 rq05d TodoItem endpoint is accessible (show and destroy) through TodoList
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_link('Show', :href => "#{todo_list_todo_item_path(tl_id, l.id)}")
expected #has_link?("Show", {:href=>"/todo_lists/832/todo_items/2538"}) to return true, got false
# ./spec/nested_resources_spec.rb:69:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /Users/subratrout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
 # /Users/subratrout/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
 # ./spec/nested_resources_spec.rb:67:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/nested_resources_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have the required show link on the page. When I check my test database I find I have todo_list with different id numbers so the test does not pass.
Every time I run a rspec the set of of todo_list get deleted and a fresh set of todo_lists is created in test database creating different primary id numbers. So the test look for previous ids of todo_lists and does not pass.

My seeds.db is as follows:

```
today = Date.today
two_days_ago = Date.today - 2.days
three_days_ago = Date.today - 3.days
dates = [today, two_days_ago, three_days_ago]

User.destroy_all
TodoList.destroy_all

100.times { |index| TodoList.create! list_name: "List #{index}", list_due_date: dates.sample }

TodoList.all.each do |list|
list.todo_items.create! [
{ title: "Task 1", due_date: dates.sample, description: "very important task TEST", completed: false },
{ title: "Task 2", due_date: dates.sample, description: "do something else TEST", completed: true},
{ title: "Task 3", due_date: dates.sample, description: "learn Action Pack TEST", completed: true}
 ]
end

users = User.create! [
{ username: "jim", password: "abc123" },
{ username: "rich", password: "123abc" }
]

TodoList.all.each do |list|
list.user = users.sample
list.save!
end
```

My rspec spec file has following:

```
context "rq05d" do

scenario "TodoItem endpoint is accessible (show and destroy) through TodoList" do
            tl_id = TodoList.all.sample.id
            list_items = TodoList.find(tl_id).todo_items
            # Confirm links in list page are nested and that the
            # show page results in expected method behavior
            list_items.each do |l|
                visit(todo_list_path(tl_id))
                expect(page).to have_link('Show', :href => "#{todo_list_todo_item_path(tl_id, l.id)}")
                expect(page).to have_link('Destroy', :href => "#{todo_list_todo_item_path(tl_id, l.id)}")
            end
        end

    end
```

And show.html.erb for Todo_list file:

```
<h1>Listing Todo Items</h1>

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Due date</th>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Description</th>
  <th>Completed</th>
  <th colspan="2"></th>
</tr>
```

```
<tbody>
<% @todo_list.todo_items.each do |todo_item| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= todo_item.due_date %></td>
    <td><%= todo_item.title %></td>
    <td><%= todo_item.description %></td>
    <td><%= todo_item.completed %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', [@todo_list, todo_item] %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', [@todo_list, todo_item], method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

My question is when I checked my test database using sqlitebrowser I am not seeing todo_list with primary id of 832 and todo_items with primary id of 2538 for /todo_lists/832/todo_items/2538. Rather I see the primary id starts after 900 for todo_lists and for todo_items it starts from 2700. Is that the reason for the test to return false value and not pass?

Comment: As it is said in database.yml
# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
Is it your case?

Comment: @Alexei.B, I have edited the question adding more information.